# problem to make turbo c++ program run with vs c++ 2010

Tags: windows

I have a code which works on turbo c++...However i would like to use it on visual studio c++ 2010 in windows 7. Is there a way to do it...If yes please let me know the same...or else what is the other way to do it...

Comment: What have you done to make it work on VS2K10?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using headers like "dos.h", "graphics.h" and so on, you won't be able even to compile your project. So, be carefull.

But there is one way to compile and run any of your projects on Windows 7 - you can install some DOS emulator or virtual machine (like VirtualBox) and use 'em for bcpp or tc. The point will be that you will be running emulation of DOS, not the native application. Thereby none of WinNT does not supports native DOS =)